# grpc: when compiling proto files into python from maven, grpc.py files are missing

Tags: python, maven, grpc, grpc-python

When I generate grpc files from python (running python -m `grpc_tools.protoc`), I get 2 files for each one of the X proto files, `X_pb2.py` and `X_pb2_grpc.py`.

However by using **compile-python** maven goal from protobuf-maven-plugin (0.6.1), I only get the X_pb2.py files and *not* the grpc files. The problem that I have with this is that the services are missing from the pb2.py files. So how can I get the grpc.py files to be built?

From pip list

```
grpcio          1.23.0 
grpcio-tools    1.23.0 
protobuf        3.9.1
```

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /blahblahblah/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the xolstice Maven plugin supports this out of the box. gRPC code generation requires a plugin to the `protoc` compiler. This plugin is baked into the `grpcio-tools` package on PyPI. You'll have to compile the Python gRPC `protoc` plugin and [supply it to protobuf-maven-plugin](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/compile-python-mojo.html) to make it work. The `protocPlugin` parameter looks like it should do what you want.

But at a higher level, is there a reason why you're using Maven to build Python artifacts?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It's a mostly-java-based project built on maven.... so, proto files are created and, **previously**, we generated java-only files... I added the support for the python files because I'm dealing with python stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with putting the compile command in a script and using the exec-maven-plugin to execute the script during compile.

I used a shell script to run a variation of the compile command from [gRPC Quick Start](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/#generate-grpc-code). A little note is that no matter where you place the script, it will be run from project root unless you navigate to another folder inside the script.